# Why does this code run so slowly?

Tags: java, performance, awt, awtrobot

I'm attempting to use these methods to find a color in a rectangular area on the screen. However there are sometimes millions of pixels on a screen, and I'm only achieving about 35 iterations of getColor a second at the moment. There must be something in my code causing this to run extremely slowly.

How can I scan my screen quicker than this? Ideally I'd like to scan the entire screen for a color in less than a second, not 8 hours as it stands now :P

Here are my two methods.

```
public static int getColor(int x, int y){
    try{
        return(robot.getPixelColor(x, y).getRGB() * -1);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("getColor ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
}

//returns first instance of color,
//Begins top left, works way down to bottom right
public static Point findColor(Box searchArea, int color){
    System.out.println("Test");
    if(searchArea.x1 > searchArea.x2){
        int temp = searchArea.x1;
        searchArea.x1 = searchArea.x2;
        searchArea.x2 = temp;
    }
    if(searchArea.y1 > searchArea.y2){
        int temp = searchArea.y1;
        searchArea.y1 = searchArea.y2;
        searchArea.y2 = temp;
    }
    for(int i = searchArea.x1;i <=searchArea.x2; i++){
        for(int j = searchArea.y1;j<=searchArea.y2;j++){
            if(getColor(i, j) == color){
                return new Point(i, j);

            }
            System.out.println(i + " " + j);
        }
    }
    return new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

Comment: maybe because it is a recursive function?

Comment: Uh oh... I just tried a for loop to a million, printing each number as it came, and it still took a full minute to complete. How can I do this if my computer(AMD FX-6300) can't even process a blank for loop fast enough?

Comment: `not 8 hours as it stands now` - really?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, my method never calls itself in the code above... And yeah, 35 iterations/second = 1 000 000 iterations/8 hours

Comment: sorry, getColor vs findColor

Comment: try profiling it with jvisualvm, 35 it/sec is very very slow, maybe getColor is very very slow?

Comment: `robot.getPixelColor` is the choke point.  It might be faster to grab a screen shot and process the resulting `BufferedImage`

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks! You should post an answer so I can give it best. I'll just process a screenshot I guess, obviously getPixelColor is simpler, but if it kills the speed by THIS much, then its useless to me.

Comment: Because it Java. Hahaha or are language wars no longer cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Robot#getColor` will be very slow, especially when used in this manner.

A better solution would be to grab a screen shot (even in small chunks) and process the resulting `BufferedImage`.

Using the following example I got...

```
Took 0 seconds to scan image
Took 3 seconds to scan screen
```

For an area of `10x10`

Example code...

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestColorGrab {

    private static Robot robot;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestColorGrab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        new TestColorGrab();
    }

    public TestColorGrab() {
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        scanImageArea(bounds);
        System.out.println("Took " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000), TimeUnit.SECONDS) + " seconds to scan image");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        scanRobotArea(bounds);
        System.out.println("Took " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000) + " seconds to scan screen");
    }

    public static int getColor(int x, int y) {
        try {
            return (robot.getPixelColor(x, y).getRGB() * -1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getColor ERROR");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void scanRobotArea(Rectangle searchArea) {
        for (int i = searchArea.x; i < searchArea.x + searchArea.width; i++) {
            for (int j = searchArea.y; j < searchArea.y + searchArea.height; j++) {
                getColor(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void scanImageArea(Rectangle searchArea) {
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(searchArea);
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                image.getRGB(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 10500 seconds to scan? I'm hoping thats a typo :P
This should work A LOT better though, I'll fiddle with it and see if I can get it to the efficiency level I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: 31000 seconds to scan a 10x10?

Comment: Time conversion was off ;)

Comment: Ahh ok phew, 0 seconds is a lot more promising ;)

Comment: Took less then a second to scan the entire screen (2560x1600) using the `BufferedImage`

Answer (score 2):

Take out the print. You are writing to the console a million times.

Comment: Scanning a 50x50, it took 76 seconds with the println, 49 seconds without. I think MadProgrammer found the biggest issue, but good to know I can't include print statements while testing efficiency